# How to add scalar value into latent variables in auto-encoder with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I've tried to input a specific scalar value(0 to 1; each image has) into a layer of latent variables.
How to insert the value in CNN based auto-encoder sequential model?

```
def encoder():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(12, (2,2), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(32, 32, 1)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding='same'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(64))
    return model

# maybe some code here

def decoder():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(16*16*12, input_shape=(65,)))
    model.add(Reshape((16,16,12)))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Conv2D(1, (2, 2), padding='same'))
    return model
```

The number of latent variables is 64 in encoder, therefore, a scalar variable should make 65 latent variables in decoder.
Concatenate layer could be applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [Concatenate layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Concatenate) for that.
For example:

```py
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8)(np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2))
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8)(np.arange(10, 20).reshape(5, 2))
concatted = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([x1, x2])
```

But you will have to choose the correct `shape` for that constant you are trying to add.

In your case, you could use:

```py
...
  outputs = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([model, your_constant])
  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=outputs)
  return model
...
```

Does this solution work for you?

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying now.